# I cant access yii2 survey extension to create form

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-module

I'm using [survey module for Yii2 application](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/onmotion/yii2-survey), but I cant access the create page of this extension.

In the page of this extension there is:

> Now go to /survey in your backend and create a survey

I also I've changed my `backend` to `fcadmin` in my project, then I use `localhost/myproject/fcadmin/survey` to access survey page, but there is **Not Found (#404)** error.

[image]

How to I have to access the page of this extension??
I really need help.

my `main config` in `fcadmin`:

```
 'modules' => [
        'survey' => [
            'class' => '\onmotion\survey\Module',
            'params' => [
                'uploadsUrl' => '@frontend/files/survey/', 
               // 'uploadsUrl' => '/uploads/survey/', 
                'uploadsPath' => '@frontend/files/survey/',
            ],
               'as access' => [
                   'class' => AccessControl::class,
                   'except' => ['default/done'],
                   'only' => ['default*'],
                   'rules' => [
                       [
                           'allow' => true,
                           'roles' => ['survey'],
                       ],
                   ],
               ],
        ],
 ]
```

Comment: what exactly is "fcadmin" in your url?

Answer (score 0):

The correct address is `localhost/yourproject/fcadmin/survey`

Comment: no is instead of backend, I've changed backend to fcadmin in my project

Comment: your edited question is still incorrect. `localhost/fcadmin/myproject/survey` should be changed to `localhost/yourproject/fcadmin/survey`. fcadmin located in your project folder.  yourproject/fcadmin/ is a correct path

Comment: is 404 error of application or web server?please provide an screenshot of error

Comment: Have you tried this? `localhost/yourproject/fcadmin/index.php/survey`

Comment: please comment 'as access' part and retry